# android layout compatibility, programmatically vs resource file, specifically for language orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

My application needs to support languages that are read from right to left and vice verca.

Right now it supports only right to left, and all I need to do is change a bunch of layouts.

The approach I want to take is to have layouts in two different folders (i.e layout and layout-de), because doing it programatically, for every layout, is a nightmare.

However, Google state here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#strategies
"you can create an alternative layout for that language (for example res/layout-de/main.xml). However, doing this can make your application harder to maintain"

My question is, which way is better, programmatically or separate layout folders

I want to stress, since this topic has been discussed in other threads:

1. I am NOT talking about strings. ONLY layouts
2. My only concern is the language orientation(left to right and right to left), when it comes to the layout.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I prefer separate layout folders way to do your requirement.

Comment: Thank you Haresh, then why would google advice against it?("However, doing this can make your application harder to maintain")?

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 4.2 there is native RTL support. Most attributes that used "left" or "right" in their names now have equivalents that use "start" and "end" (e.g. `android:paddingStart="..."` or `android:gravity="end"`).

Read about it here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: Thanks Karakuri, however rtl is only supported for api 17 and up. I have to support for lower than that. so does that mean the best solution is to have seperate folders (values, values-de etc)?